# What are names and dates in this Status Animarum for Gregorcčič at Roženberk 6?

Tags: 19th-century, palaeography, austria-hungary, kurrent, vital-records

Here is a German [Status Animarum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parish_family_book) for the Roženberk 6 household in the Šentrupert parish in the early 1800s.  I've added what I think are the names and dates as written in German, but expect I have errors as I'm slowly learning to read the [Kurrent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurrent) handwriting used here.

[image]

Please help with any corrections and filling in sections I couldn't figure out, including what is crossed out.

---

Update, here is S.A. from next book in the series covering 1775 to 1880:

[image]

---

Update, here is baptismal record covering Roženberk from 1804 to 1822 and has Andreas Gregorčič listed many times with yet another wife whose name I cannot make out yet, but appears to be something like Luzia Onmcciz.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Corrections

```
Andreas Gregorzhizh ...
Sohn, Johann    12 Apr. '811      30 ??? ??? Hube?
do. Mathia ...
do. Andreas ...
Tochter, Anna    18. Apr. '809  
         unehel. T. [=uneheliche Tochter, =illegitimate daughter] Agnes am 17 Januar '840
         dto Anna 26 April '842
...
Ursula, 2t. Ehe [=2nd marriage] ...
```

I think the struckout duplicate entry of Agnes is indicating that this child was originally recorded as Maria's daughter, but really was Anna's

In response to comments:

Re: 26 April 1842 - this birthdate belongs to Anna, a 2nd illegitimate daughter of Anna and sister to Agnes. Note the "dto" directly below the "unehel. T." of the previous line.

Re: Ursula - <strike>probably the 1st Andreas 2nd wife (given the usual format of these registers - Familienbuch is the name I am more familiar with). However,</strike> the date column is birth date in every other case, so I would look for the relevant death and marriage records for corroboration and sequence. I also considered the partial stroke through Ursula's name, deciding it was a slip of the pen, since it was not horizontal nor through the whole name and there was no accompanying correction or explanation.

Re: Re: Ursula - As suggested previously, other records helped explain the family structure and showed that Ursula is probably a DAUGHTER of the 2nd marriage of Andreas, that is, her parents were Andreas and Maria. That Andreas had been married previously was hinted by the fact that wife Maria would have been only 11 and 13 at the births of children Anna and Johann. BTW, the Status Animarum records should be treated more like parish censuses than a compendium of family events: The births register includes children of Andreas and his 1st wife Luzia Semezouka? Semnitz? Semniz? (different spellings in different entries) that are not in the household of the 1st image posted, including triplets born in 1818 (Martin, Michael and an earlier Ursula).

Comment: Is Ursula the second marriage of Andreas, suggesting his first wife, Maria died and thus Ursula is the mother of son Andreas?

Comment: So Agnes is daughter of Anna with unknown father, but what is second date of 26 Apr 1842?  Was that death of daughter Agnes or date she married and made the child legitimate?

Comment: I've found a later record showing that 1st Andreas died in 1860 and his wife Maria died after 1863, so the 2nd wife Ursula must be second wife to another person, but no one else in the household even has a first wife, so something is not quite correct here in the analysis.  See added photo in question.

Comment: I think the second marriage Ursula at bottom of first record cannot be to first Andreas since the later S.A. (now added) shows Maria as wife again and no Ursula listed.  Plus, Ursula being born 1821 is 37 years younger than Andreas.

Comment: Could Ursula be a child from second marriage where Maria is second wife after first wife, Luzia, not shown in S.A.?

Comment: I think that's it - Ursula is a daughter of 2nd marriage, and the words "Tochter" or "dto." were omitted and were to be assumed because of the position in the child list.

Answer (score 3):

A few corrections:

- Audmnad = Andreas
- Aiuer = Anna
- Martin = Mathia(s)?

Not sure about the surname.